# ModelMetadata.ContainerType returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I want to write an HTML helper method. In my helper method I want to know what is the type of the main model (if any). To obtain that, I used `htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType` , but I can't find any way to do that when my helper is called in a template view or probably a partial view whose model is an item of a collection. In this case `htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType` returns null.

Sample Model:

```
public class MyItemCollection
{
   public List<MyItemContainer> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

Sample EditorTemplate:

```
@model Test.MyItemContainer

@Html.MyHelper(m=>m.Item)
```

Sample View:

```
@model Test.MyItemCollection

@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Collection.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Collection[i])
}
```

Sample Action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var m = new MyItemCollection();
   //Fetching items from Business Logic
   m.Collection = FetchItems();
   return View(m);
}
```

Comment: Are you passing an instance on MyItemContainer to the View in your Action?  Please show the code in your action.  Specifically, where you return the View(model)

Comment: [This](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html) might be out of date, but possible still valid.

Comment: Hi, @GlennFerrie. Yes, I am passing an instance of MyItemCollection that its Collection property contains instances of items. I am edited my question.

Comment: what does fetch items do?

Comment: consider changing Fetchitems to return IEnumerable<MyItemContainer> and fill the list with Collection.AddRange(FetchItems());

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should create an empty constructor for `MyItemCollection` and then initialize the `Collection` property.

In the case where that element isn't being intialized by another procedure it will result in `NULL` which could, in turn, cause the possible Reflection-related issue you are experiencing (i.e: finding `ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType`)

I say, initialize the property yourself.  see below

```
public class MyItemCollection
{
     // added a constructor, so we could initialize Collection.
     public MyItemCollection()
     {
         this.Collecion = new List<MyItemContainer>();
     }

     public List<MyItemContainer> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @glenn I tried your solution, and created a constructor that initialize `Collection` but no change was made in result. Still `ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType' returns null.